# Forcing Symfony form validation without actual submission

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Is it possible to perform form fields validation manually, forced?

I have a form. It has a global form validation. Everything works well if user submits data.

But I want to trigger validation before form is displayed to the user - show errors before submit.

Tried to submit using `$form->submit([])` method but it doesn't trigger form fields validation.

Any ideas on this issue? Did I something wrong?

Comment: How can possibly a form have errors BEFORE it is submitted?!

Comment: @DonCallisto - I fill up the form with data from external service. Moreover - I want to show user *form* errors (which have instruction which fields need to be mapped).

Comment: considering to use a js field validator approach. There are some bundle already do this works, as example https://github.com/formapro/JsFormValidatorBundle

Comment: @Matteo - isn't there any simple solution to JUST fire validation one more time? Is really separated bundle needed for such a simple task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason was quite complicated and simple at once.

```
// form instantiation

$type = new MyType();

$options = [
    'csrf_protection'=>!empty($_POST[$type->getName()])
];

$form = $this->createForm($type, [/* or entity */], $options);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if(!$form->isSubmitted()){
    $form->submit([]);
}
```

And now I can see errors correctly. One of the most tricky part is the fact I wasn't aware Form `$options` are read-only after creation and `empty` check is mandatory if you want to leave CSRF protection turned on.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to validate a data only by form? Doesn't a validator service work for you?

Like

```
$violations = $this->get('validator')->validate($entity);
```

Comment: If you want to map the violations to a form... it seems there is no simple way to do it after validating the entity as the ViolationMapper is looking for PropertyPaths prefixed with "children" which an entity validation does not do.

Comment: _Doesn't a validator service work for you?_ No it does not because of Form constraints for a form not mapped to an entity...

Answer (score 0):

Invoke `$form->isValid();` before showing the form.

However If data come from an external service, I would rather prevent (with ws validation, for example) users to submit wrong data through ws (ws = external service)

Comment: ``isValid`` invokes only gathering ``errors`` protected property. It's populated during ``submit`` function but the only check available is the CSRF token validation...

Comment: So I'm not sure I understood what you need

Comment: I've set some data using ``setData`` method. And I want to perform validation against this data, then - show end-user validation results using standard form error views, just like user clicked "submit" button.